# Finding watchOS version programmatically

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I want to find the watchOS version of the Apple Watch which is paired with the iOS device.

The following code works for iOS devices, but I couldn't figure out a way to find the watchOS version:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion]
```

And also, with iOS 9.3 and watchOS 2.2 we will be allowed to pair with more than one watches. So, is there any way I can get details of all paired watches programatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the below code to get watch kit details

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

The details can be found in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice).

Comment: For clarity, this API is watchOS 2.0+

Answer (score 1):

Swift version.

```
let watchOSVersion = WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
print("WatchOS version: \(watchOSVersion)")
```